# Problemas con Agregar y Remover Componentes usando validate() y repaint() en Java

Tags: java, validación, interfaz-gráfica, gridlayaout, repaint

En un proyecto Java que Realizo tengo varios `JCheckbox` los cual al estar seleccionados muestran un panel con un campo de texto.

El Problema es que quisiera, que se fueran acomodando conforme se van seleccionando y se agradable al usuario.

Tengo el siguiente Código:

```
if (chkId.isSelected()) {
  pnlFilText.add(pnlFilID);
} else {
  pnlFilText.remove(pnlFilID);
}
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Mis componentes se van agregando, pero de repente como si se recargara se vuelven ordenar de distinta forma, desconozco el por que se cambian.

Comment: Cuando instancies esos componentes no los agregues al panel manualmente; lo agregas/quitas de acuerdo al estado del `JCheckBox`, la lógica es: *si opcion está en* `true` *entonces agrega componente, si opción está* `false` *entonces quita componente*

Comment: @JohnnyTB hice lo de remover los componentes y todo bien, el problema es que se empiezan a reordenar.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es que mantengan el mismo orden en que están dispuestos los `JCheckBox` se me ocurre usar una lista con todos los `JTextField`, cuando se haga click en cualquier `JCheckBox` el cual quede en `true` entonces se vacía el contenedor `pnlFilText` y después se recorre el contenedor de *check boxes* para ver cuales tienen ese `true`, finalmente con el indice se referencia el `JTextField` respectivo de la lista.

Algo mas o menos de este estilo.

```
private void toggle(ActionEvent evt) {
  if(evt.getSource()instanceof JCheckBox) {
    JCheckBox C=((JCheckBox)evt.getSource());
    int index=chkPane.getComponentZOrder(C);
    if(C.isSelected()) {
      pnlFilText.removeAll();
      for(int i=0;i<chkPane.getComponentCount();i++) {
        if(((JCheckBox)chkPane.getComponent(i)).isSelected())
          pnlFilText.add(tFields.get(i));
      }
    } else {
      pnlFilText.remove(tFields.get(index));
    }
  }
  revalidate();
  repaint();
}
```